# How to calculate Percentage out of Total value in DAX (Power BI Desktop)

Tags: dax, percentage, powerbi-desktop

I have the following Slicer in Power BI Desktop, where **# of Clients** is calculated as **Count(Distinct(Fact.EHRTransaction.ClientFK))** in my data model:

[image]

My goal is to calculate **Percentage out of Total (13 639)** and add it to this slicer as a Measure or another Column, like:

```
     Gender      # of Clients   Total Clients
     Unknown               2          0.00%
     Intersex             13          0.00%
     Transgender          18          0.00%
     Female              662          0.04%
     Male                832          0.05%
     (Not Recorded)   12 112         72.79%
```

I tried adding the following Column:

```
   Percentage = 'FactEHRClinicalTransaction'[ClientFK]/            
   CALCULATE(SUM('FactEHRClinicalTransaction'[ClientFK]),ALLSELECTED())
```

But I am getting an incorrect values -

[image]

Please, help or advice!

Update: 
Finally, found a solution:
In order to achieve these calculations, needed to add a **Measures** for each operation. And then, use them (not the fields) in final % calculation -

```
    # of Clients = DISTINCTCOUNT('Fact EHRClinicalTransaction'[ClientFK]) 

    # of Clients_Total = 
         CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Fact EHRClinicalTransaction'[ClientFK]), 
                               ALLSELECTED('Fact EHRClinicalTransaction'))

   % of Clients = DIVIDE('Fact EHRClinicalTransaction' 
  [# of Clients],'Fact EHRClinicalTransaction'[# of Clients_Total])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you are missing an aggregation in the first part of your division and are summing the FKs in the second part instead of counting. Try this:

```
Percentage =
DIVIDE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'FactEHRClinicalTransaction'[ClientFK] ),
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'FactEHRClinicalTransaction'[ClientFK] ),
        ALLSELECTED ()
    )
)
```

Using DIVIDE() makes for a safer division.

Comment: @janvanwekhoven  Unfortunately, I am getting the numbers, like this, after adding your code - 434103.00  ....

Comment: @janvanwekhoven Finally worked with your suggestions, Thank you!

Comment: What is  ALLSELECTED () here?