# Calculate percent of total considering applied filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to calculate Percentage value of total (same as inbuilt "show as -> percentage of grand total" but using DAX).

I have seen solutions
[Percent of Total Windowed in Power BI DAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393069/percent-of-total-windowed-in-power-bi-dax)
and
[Power BI DAX - Percent of Total Column with FILTERs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61879425/power-bi-dax-percent-of-total-column-with-filters)
and
[How to calculate Percentage out of Total value in DAX (Power BI Desktop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57403669/how-to-calculate-percentage-out-of-total-value-in-dax-power-bi-desktop)

but unfortunately all of them do not work for me (I get all rows filled with 100% for calculated column)

Idea is to have percetage of total but be able to apply date filter and see percent value of shown data, not entiry query
I tried as in above mentioned solutions:

```
Percentage = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM( All_Years[Price:] ),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM( All_Years[Price:] ),
        ALLSELECTED( All_Years )
    )
)
```

First of all I do not understand why do they take SUM in numerator. If I use just

```
Percentage = 
DIVIDE(
    All_Years[Price:],
    CALCULATE(
        SUM( All_Years[Price:] ),
        ALLSELECTED( All_Years )
    )
)
```

then situation looks better, I get percent value of total table in each row. But then when I apply date filter in Visual I see total 3.5% (which is correct if we consider full query and not slice that I got after applying filter)
[image]

Leaving ALLSELECTED blank also does not resolve the problem.
what am I missing?

Comment: You should use Measure instead of using a Calculated Column. We use sum, to get correct value in different scenarios (group by Column1 or Column2 etc).

Comment: @msta42, then drill down will not work. I need to avoid measures. Is there any way?

Comment: To get the "correct" result after applying some filter, we need measure, because Calculate Column is pre-calculated and the output will not dynamically changed.

Maybe you can use drillthrough:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-drillthrough

Comment: @msta42a, ok, got it, then this is probably not for me. Will just create two visuals with perc and without. Then in-built "show as percentage" is the simplest solution. Thanks you!